# Consulta con Inner Join

Tags: mysql, sql

Hace unos días hice una pregunta para sacar datos de una BD relacionando varias tablas con el `**INNER JOIN**`.

Ahora estoy intentando mezclar el `INNER` y el `COUNT` pero no sé cómo expresarlo.

Tengo estas tablas.

Tabla: **w_clientes**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tabla: **w_reservas**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero hacer es una consulta que saque desde un intervalo de fechas la lista de clientes ordenados por el número de clases que han reservado en ese periodo.

La consulta que hice hace unos días, hacía algo parecido. Mostrar nombre de reserva y nombre de cliente.

```
SELECT cl.nombre,c.nombre From wp_ac_reservas r 
INNER JOIN wp_ac_clases cl on r.id_clase =cl.id 
INNER JOIN wp_ac_clientes c on c.id = r.id_usuario 
WHERE r.fecha_reserva BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-03-31'
```

Pero ahora necesito sólo **Nombre de cliente, apellidos y número de reservas desde x hasta x fecha** (habría que meter un `count` por medio supongo)

Agradezco desde ya el interés.

Comment: Échate un ojo a [GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html). Estoy convencido de que simplemente leyendo como funciona puedes sacar la respuesta a la pregunta sin problemas ;)

Comment: @frikinside lo que no entiendo es cómo puedo combinar con el inner, primero tengo que usar el inner para unir clientes y reservas

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar `COUNT (*)` y luego agrupar por el `id_cliente`:

***Aquí se muestra la cantidad de reservas de todos los clientes en un rango de fechas***

```
SELECT
  c.nom_cliente, COUNT(*) as total
FROM
  w_clientes c
INNER JOIN 
  w_reservas r
ON c.id_cliente=r.id_cliente
WHERE r.fecha_reserva BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-12-31'
GROUP BY c.id_cliente;
```

***Aquí se muestra la cantidad de reservas de un cliente en específico en un rango de fechas***

Yo separaría los dos criterios del `WHERE`, para evitar sorpresas.

```
SELECT
  c.nom_cliente, COUNT(*) as total
FROM
  w_clientes c
INNER JOIN 
  w_reservas r
ON c.id_cliente=r.id_cliente
WHERE (r.fecha_reserva BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-12-31') AND (c.id_cliente=1)
GROUP BY c.id_cliente;
```

---

**EJEMPLO COMPLETO**

En el ejemplo se cuentan solamente las reservas entre las fechas indicadas, ignorando las del año 2018.

[**DEMO SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/86d607/3)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE w_clientes
    (`id_cliente` int, `nom_cliente` varchar(70))
;

INSERT INTO w_clientes
    (`id_cliente`, `nom_cliente`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Pedro'),
    (2, 'Santiago'),
    (3, 'Juan')
;


CREATE TABLE w_reservas
    (`id_reserva` int, `id_cliente` int, `fecha_reserva` date )
;

INSERT INTO w_reservas
    (`id_reserva`, `id_cliente`, `fecha_reserva`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, '2017-01-05'),
    (2, 1, '2017-02-05'),
    (3, 1, '2017-03-05'),
    (4, 2, '2017-04-05'),
    (5, 3, '2017-09-06'),
    (6, 1, '2017-08-05'),
    (7, 3, '2018-01-01'),
    (8, 2, '2018-01-02'),
    (9, 1, '2018-02-07')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT
  c.nom_cliente, COUNT(*) as total
FROM
  w_clientes c
INNER JOIN 
  w_reservas r
ON c.id_cliente=r.id_cliente
WHERE r.fecha_reserva BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-12-31'
GROUP BY c.id_cliente
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/86d607/3/0)**:

```
| nom_cliente | total |
|-------------|-------|
|       Pedro |     4 |
|    Santiago |     1 |
|        Juan |     1 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo una consulta hecha al "vuelo", así que puede que haya algo que no funcione bien del todo. Básicamente, lo que tienes que hacer es agrupar por el valor que te interese y sacar el conteo. Algo así:

```
select w_clientes.id_usuario, w_clientes.nombre, count(w_clientes.id_usuario)
from w_clientes
inner join w_reservas on w_reservas.id_usuario = w_clientes.id_usuario
where w_reservas.fecha_reserva>='2017-01-01' and w_reservas.fecha_reserva<='2017-03-30'
group by w_clientes.id_usuario, w_clientes.nombre
```

Espero que te sirva

Answer (score 0):

No queda claro que es lo que quieres hacer con el count, si contar cuantos registros hay, contar cuantas reservas ha hecho un cliente o simplemente has mal interpretado que es lo que pienso.

Así puedes obtener un listado de los registros con nombre y apellidos y id_reserva he obviado el count pues de tu pregunta interpreto que realmente no es lo que necesitas.

```
SELECT 
/* decimos que columnas queremos */
   c.nombre,
   c.apellido,
   r.id id_reserva
FROM 
/* indicamos la tabla principal de la consulta */
    w_clientes c
INNER JOIN 
/* unimos otra tabla por su relación  con la principal */
    w_reservas r ON c.id_usuario = r.id_usuario 
WHERE 
/* indicamos las condiciones que deben cumplir los registros */
    r.fecha_reserva BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-03-31'
/* ordenamos los registros en base a la columna o columnas que indiquemos */
ORDER BY r.id_clase ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Todas las respuestas que te han estado dando son válidas, pero según el criterio pueden ser ambiguas. Cuando la necesidad es ¿Quiero saber la cantidad de reservas que tiene cada cliente? y tenemos clientes que no tienen reservas ¿Como los mostramos?  ¿Los mostramos?. Los ejemplos que te han pasado no los muestran, entonces, para completar un poco, te adjunto un ejemplo dónde se mostrará 0 en la cantidad de reservas cuando el cliente no tuviera. Este criterio es más específico y claro para algunos usuarios, pero claramente puede hacer informes extremadamente largos.

```
select  c.nombre,
    c.apellidos,
    ISNULL(count(r.id_reserva),0) AS 'Cantidad'
    from w_clientes c
    left join w_reservas r
        on r.id_cliente = c.id_cliente
        and r.fecha_reserva BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-03-31'
    group by 
        c.nombre,
        c.apellidos
```